# How statement is covered in Karma?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am doing testing using karma tool. I am not able to covered code inside foreach statement. Please let me know how i can coverage this code using jasmine test case.

[image]

I have written below suite in jasmine for this.

```
 describe('Employee test', function () {
    beforeEach(() => {
        module('app');
        inject((_$controller_: ng.IControllerService, _$httpBackend_: ng.IHttpBackendService, $http: ng.IHttpService) => {

                httpB = _$httpBackend_;
                http = $http;
                empService = new EmployeeService($http);

                ctrl = $controller("employeeCtrl", { $scope: $scope, empService });
        });
    it("controller constructor",() => {
                empService.testdata = [];
                var ctrlObj = new employeeCtrlClass($scope, empService);
        });
     });
```

here , I am creating employeeCtrlClass object so that it is indirectly called the constructor of function. but it is not able to called **foreach** statement.

Comment: Without test data, how do you expect to go through the properties of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put some data into the `testdata` array:

```
empService.testdata = [
    {
        empId: 1,
        empData: {}
    }
];
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is not working. Still it is showing uncovered.